# Multiple l2cache issues are in gem5

Tags: gem5

I'm using the MESI_Two_Level protocol, and the following is the command line I'm using, these 16 L2s correspond to each private L1I/D, so L2 contains the contents of L1, but what I want to know is whether the L2 between each other will also have the same block

> build/X86/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --ruby -n 16 --l1i_size=2kB --l1d_size=1kB --l2_size=8kB --l1i_assoc=2 --l1d_assoc=2 --l2_assoc=4 --num-l2caches=16 --num-dirs=16 --topology=Mesh_XY --mesh-rows=4 --cacheline_size=64 --network=simple --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU

Comment: I'm not sure, but have a look at `m5out/config.ini`, it contains a tree representing the system via `children` nodes. Also `m5out/conifg.ini.pdf` has a visual representation. If that doesn't help, post on the mailing list.